# Which will be the largest and which the smallest eigenvalue of inverse of A?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix and $0 <  \lambda_1 \le  \lambda_2 \le \cdots \le\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$.

Which will be the largest and which the smallest eigenvalue of inverse of $A$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about the case in which $A$ is diagonal, that might inspire you.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have:
$$
Av=\lambda v \iff A^{-1}Av=\lambda A^{-1}v \iff A^{-1}v=\frac{1}{\lambda} v
$$
so if the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n\}$, the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the inverses.